# Finding the minimum value in an array

Tags: c

Let's suppose we have an array with any size, so when we're putting the values for each section of the array, we need to show the minimum value of it, and we should be able to see its position.

I tried to write a code where I can do that, but I don't know how to continue my code. I'm gonna show how far I've gone.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main ()
{
   int tv,vv,V[10];

   printf(" Ingrese el tamaño del vector: \n");
   scanf("%d",&tv);
   printf(" Ingrese los valores del vector: \n");
   scanf("%d",&vv);

   for (int i = 1; i <= tv; i++)
   {
      scanf("%d",&V[i]);
   }

   for (int i = 1; i <= tv; i++)
   {
      if (V[i]<vv)
      {
         
      }
   }     
}
```

I hope someone can guide me.

psdt: the whole code was written in Spanish.

Comment: Are you using `C` or `C++`?

Comment: This is clearly C code, not C++ code. The term 'vector' has a very different meaning in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what the purpose of the variable vv is supposed to do, but hopefully this is helpful:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// #define READ_FROM_SDTIN // uncomment to read values from stdin

int main ()
{
#ifdef READ_FROM_SDTIN  
   int tv,vv,V[10];
   int minvalue, minpos;

   
   printf(" Ingrese el tamaño del vector: \n");
   scanf("%d",&tv);
   printf(" Ingrese los valores del vector: \n");
   scanf("%d",&vv);

   for (int i = 1; i <= tv; i++)
   {
      scanf("%d",&V[i]);
   }
#else
   // test data
   int tv;
   int minvalue, minpos;
   int V[10] = {3,6,5,3,9,20,0,4,6,7};

   tv = 10;
#endif


   minvalue = V[0];
   minpos = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < tv; i++)
   {
      if (V[i]<minvalue)
      {
         minvalue = V[i];
         minpos = i;
      }
   }
  
   printf("minimum value %d\n",minvalue);
   printf("minimum value position %d\n",minpos);
   return 0;
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
minimum value 0
minimum value position 6
```

which is the desired answer for the test data.

Comment: Thank you, it was really really helpful

Comment: @PeterNarváez, would you mind marking it as the accepted answer?